# How to resolve "unknown op" error with Powertop on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: powertop

when I type:

```
sudo powertop
```

I got the following error:

```
unknown op '{'
            Model-specific registers (MSR)           not found (try enabling CONFIG_X86_MSR).
                     read_msr cpu2 0x60d : No such file or directory
```

Can any one help?

Comment: What CPU type do you use?

Comment: My CPU is intel core i5

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug which has no effect on the program.

[PowerTop 2.7 details](https://01.org/powertop/downloads/powertop-v2.7-0)

> Known Bugs
>   (we plan to fix these bugs in future releases):
>
> - Problem with traceevent lib it prints string: unknown op '{'.  This bug doesn’t impact the correct functionality of PowerTOP.
> - PowerTOP shows all CPUs Idle 99% and 600 MHz is always around 1% even when executing a workload.  This happens when setting the Frequency stats to powersave governor.
> - PowerTOP Summary CPU usage over 100%

Answer (score 2):

The `powertop` command requires the `msr` kernel module. The mention of `CONFIG_X86_MSR` in the error message is a reference to a kernel configuration option. On my Ubuntu system it is defined as follows:

```
CONFIG_X86_MSR=m
```

which means that it is configured as a kernel module. When I run powertop my `msr` kernel module is loaded automatically. A value of `y` rather than `m` would compile `msr` directly into the kernel, while a value of `n` would disable it altogether.

You should be able to determine the value of `CONFIG_X86_MSR` on your Ubuntu system by looking in the correct `/boot/config-*` file. For example, on my Ubuntu system the relevant file is `/boot/config-4.4.0-31-generic`. If you have more than one such file the output of `uname -r` should tell you which one corresponds to your running kernel.

One place to start is to determine the value of `CONFIG_X86_MSR`. If you didn't build a custom kernel `m` is a likely value for that. If the value is `n` you'll probably need to build a new kernel configured differently, or boot a stock kernel with `CONFIG_X86_MSR` enabled (with either `y` or `m`). If the value is `m`, you should check whether the `msr` is loaded. If it isn't loaded, `modprobe msr` should load it, if it's installed properly.

One other thing worth checking is whether your running kernel corresponds to the newest installed kernel. If your kernel was upgraded without a subsequent reboot, that might prevent the `msr` module from loading properly.

Comment: CONFIG_X86_MSR=m
this is what is set in my config file and i typed "madprobe msr" in terminal and then "sudo powertop" but again the same error

Comment: That makes sense, since it seems to be the default. Is your `msr` module loaded? One way to check that is output from `lsmod`.

Comment: vmw_pvscsi      
vmxnet3      
hid_generic       
usbhid       
hid       
psmouse     
mptspi       
e1000      
vmwgfx       
ahci      
libahci       
ttm       
mptscsih     
drm_kms_helper     
mptbase       
syscopyarea     
sysfillrect      
sysimgblt     
fb_sys_fops      
scsi_transport_spi    
drm     
pata_acpi    
fjes

Comment: Have you tried `modprobe msr` yet? If that fails, see the latest edit to my answer.

Comment: yes i use 'madprobe msr' and i reboot again, but nothing change yet

Comment: Do you get error output from `modprobe`? (If you really spelled it as `madprobe` that should report an error)

Comment: it was mistake, i copy-paste from your comment and again powertop dont run

Comment: I using vm-ware , this is my project,, ubuntu 16.94 is running on it,  is that effective?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but the Ubuntu system I'm using for this is a virtual machine running on ESXi.

Comment: my lsdmod:

http://uploads.im/GaKcR.png